# Enviar email desde C++ (boost)

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Tengo un servidor *Ubuntu* donde se ejecuta una aplicación hecha en *C++* que usa la librería *boost* para enviar correo electrónico desde una cuenta de *GMail*. Esta parte del programa la hizo otra persona con la que ya no tengo contacto.

Ahora he creado un **servidor gemelo (servidor B)** con la misma aplicación. Cuando el programa en el **servidor B** intenta enviar un email sólo escribe el log **email not present**.

Creo que es obvio que hay algo fuera de la aplicación *C++* que está en el **servidor A** y no en el **B**, y es lo que hace que el **A** envíe correos y el **B** no pueda.

Me dí cuenta de que el servidor **A** tenía el demonio **sendmail** funcionando y el **B** no, así que instalé *Sendmail* en el servidor **B** y copié los archivos de configuración. No hubo suerte. Quizá olvidé copiar algo ó quizá *Sendmail* no es lo que se está usando para enviar los correos.

Comment: The language of this site is Spanish, please translate the question or use the english version of StackOverflow

Comment: Perdón. Es la costumbre.

Comment: Lo primero que tienes que hacer es averiguar como se mandan los correos en A. Puede ser mediante conexión _SMTP_, o bien invocando un comando. Te sugiero que consultes la doc de `strace` y `ltrace`, o bien busques en el código llamadas a ' execXX( )` o el uso de clases `asio` de red. Cuando sepas como se envian, ya podremos seguir haciendo algo :-)

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Mientras miro lo de strace y ltrace, aquí te dejo la función que envía los emails:

Comment: void Ejecutor::SendMail(const SEmail &em)

{
    
std::stringstream ss;

    
ss << "echo \"" << em.mensaje << "\" | mail -s \"" << em.asunto << "\" " << em.destinatario;
    
int result = system(ss.str().c_str());

}

Comment: em.destinatario y em.asunto son campos std::string de la estructura SEmail  &em

Comment: Vale, creo que tengo claro por dónde van los tiros.

Comment: Ya lo tienes hecho; haberlo dicho ;-) `system(ss.str().c_str());`. Envia el correo mediante un comando. Pues hala, a instalar un cliente _SMTP_ compatible con _senmail_, o a investigar como se configura adecuadamente. Me parece que no es tan simple como copiar la configuración de un lado a otro ;-)

Comment: Para que puedas ir buscando: creo que lo que tienes que hacer es configurar el _sendmail_ en el nuevo equipo como `relay host`. O algo así :-)

Comment: No me había dado cuenta de que en realidad se estaba lanzando un comando. Me estaba liando con otras partes del código. ¡Lo tenía delante y no lo veía!. Cuando lanzo ese comando a mano en la consola me dice "the program 'mail' is currently not installed'. Parece fácil, ¿no?

Comment: ¡Ya funciona! Sólo había que instalar mailutils y ssmtp. Muchas gracias.